Is there an easy way to put left right limits the Filling option?
Consider the following plot.
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]


I would like the plot to only shade in the area enclosed by the two curves (the area between x=0 and x=1).  I can't seem to find an easy way to put left/right limits on the Filling option. Does anyone know a nice trick for this?
I know I can use RegionPlot[] or RegionFunction[] to shade the bounded area, but it seems like there must be a more efficient way by using the Filling option alone.  Maybe not.

Show[Plot[{x,x^2},{x,-2,2}],Plot[{x,x^2},{x,0,1},PlotLegends->"Expressions",Filling->{1->{2}}]] only took a couple of seconds to do and worked on the very first try, but I acknowledge that this will almost certainly be unacceptable.

I should have thought of that. haha!  Better than using RegionPlot.  Thanks!

You can specify different filling styles depending on which curve is larger.
Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {None, Automatic}}}]



Nice, documented solution. (+1)
